# 404 page not found in WordPress localhost

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a website called  http://www.aarohanstudycircle.com/ running successfully on a server but when I downloaded all the wp files/folder and imported the database to localhost. I am getting the page not found error.[Here is the error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB1MS.png)

http://localhost/aarohanstudycircle/public/

Answer (score 0):

Why your URL is going Like `http://localhost/aarohanstudycircle/public/` ??

Is it a public folder or file you are trying to access ?

If it is a folder then you have to move all files to the root folder of your project and then remove any directory.

Once you do this then you can access the URL 
like this -

> **http://localhost/ProjectName**

Good Luck!

Comment: i had moved all files from public to the root folder aarohanstudycircle http://localhost/aarohanstudycircle  ...but getting the same error 404 not found

Comment: open database table called wp-options and check out first two rows called site_url. Change site url and project url to your localhost url instead of live url.

Comment: I had done as you said Siteurl: localhost/aarohanstudycircle , Home: localhost/aarohanstudycircle ,eventhough..i am getting the same error  page not found...i can see only header and fotter not the the content..

Comment: Solved ..i have to use like this http://localhost/aarohanstudycircle not localhost/aarohanstudycircle ..thank you Mr. Jainish Patel..

Comment: Now homepage is working but when i click on the other page 
 http://localhost/aarohanstudycircle/about-institute  i get this error :-     
 Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 17

Comment: send me Screenshot of otherpage you've opened

Comment: I think you should refer some wordpress tutorials for basic understanding of wordpress hierarchy and project deployment.

Comment: please resolve this error ..i will gald to you for this please